# Rails forms for has_many through association using cocoon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, drop-down-menu, simple-form, cocoon-gem

i have used has-many-through relation between  user and skills with  bridge table skills_users. I have used cocoon gem. i am getting values from skills using dropdown box on each add_association. In adding new skill the dropdown shows all the values but i want only values that have not been selected. is there any way to reject values that have already been selected from dropbox of new skills

```
class SkillsUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :skill
 belongs_to :user
end

class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :skills_users
 has_many :users, through: :skills_users
 belongs_to :skill_type
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :skills_users
 has_many :skills, through: :skills_users
end
```

here is my drop-down box code for skills

```
 = f.input :skill_id, as: :select, collection: Skill.where(skill_type: skill_type.id), label_method: :name, value_method: :id,  label: false,  placeholder: 'Add Skills'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller add:

```
@available_skills = Skill.where(skill_type: skill_type).where("`id` not in ?", @user.skills.pluck(:id))
```

then in your view:

```
 = f.input :skill_id, as: :select, collection: @available_skills, label_method: :name, value_method: :id,  label: false,  placeholder: 'Add Skills'
```

Comment: this is good for controller to view the available skills.

but my problem is that i want this functionality on view.
suppose  i have 3 skills in my database. i have shown them in dropdown. if i have selected the first skill then the successive dropdown displays only remaining two fields

Comment: That would require some javascript; Basically you'd have to export the list of skills to javascript, then for each dropdown on your screen you'd have to trigger a onSelect and re-assert what options to display in the other dropdowns, definitely not trivial JS.

Comment: I would suggest looking at something like: http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-multiselect-plugin/